# Does minimizing the action for a lagrangian also minimize the action for the square of the lagrangian?

Tags: optimization, calculus-of-variations

Let's say I have found the path for which the action:

$$
S = \int_{x_1}^{x_2}\mathcal{L}(y(x),y'(x),x) dx
$$

Is minimized. Does this mean that this path minimizes the integral of the square of the Lagrangian? I have started sketching a proof by considering the variation of the integral of $\mathcal{L}^2$, but have hit a wall trying to integrate by parts. If this does not hold in general, are there conditions on $\mathcal{L}$ for which this is true?

Comment: I think that the Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}(x,y(x),y'(x)) = y(x)^2 - 1$ on the interval $[0,1]$ is a counterexample. The action is minimized to $-1$ with the path $y \equiv 0$, where as the action of the square is minimized to $0$ with the path $y \equiv 1$, in particular, if we set $y \equiv 0$ in the second case, then the action will be $1$.